# How can I get rid of double spaces? (Python)

Tags: python, integer, whitespace

I have a data file (`.txt`) containing some lines, each line as following:

`0  45  1  31  2  54  3  54  4  64`

With a white space before zero, two spaces between each two integers and a white space at the end. What I want is to have it like following:

`0 45 1 31 2 54 3 54 4 64`

I am trying everything (using Python) but I am not successful!

Of course at the end I want to reform it to:

`45 31 54 54 64`

That is eliminating the numbers 0 to 4 as well. But this last step is maybe easier to do if I reach the first one.

For example I have tried this:

```
with open('myfile', rt') as openfile, open('myfile_2, 'a') as csvfile:
    for line in openfile:
            A = str(line).replace('  ', ' ')
            Writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar=' ')
            Writer.writerow([A])
```

But yet in the `myfile_2' the string is not corrected.

Comment: You have tried everything? Could you give some examples?

Comment: When you say "of course you want to reform it to:" you present something which is not at all obvious. You also haven't provided any code indicating you have tried. Try the string method `replace`, `split` and then look at list slicing

Comment: You may go with `' '.join(yourString.split())`, of course you have to load your file first.

Comment: Certainly your post lacks what you've tried so far. But I think you should also try to describe the goal you want to achieve, because I feel that "getting rid of double spaces" is only the way you _think_ you need to achieve your goal. But I dare to guess your goal can be achieved easier...

Comment: try this: `text.replace(DOUBLESPACE, SINGLESPACE).strip()`

Comment: Sure if I could do it I didn't post it here. Not a good manner to blame for not trying after 30 seconds of posting. I was just completing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made Changes Accordingly:

```
with open('newtes.txt', 'w') as outfile, open('tes.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.replace('  ',' ').strip())
```

edit 1 : strip() added as suggested in the comment 
edit 2 : Made Changes.

Comment: add `.strip()` to remove space in the begining and end.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the same thing, and when I print it is correct, but in the file `myfile_2` I have still two spaces.

Comment: Check the snippet now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is working, but all lines are in a row, I mean there is no line break.

Comment: So I added `outfile.write('\n')` as a new line at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re` instead:

```
import re
# Handles multiple whitespaces
WHITE_SPACE_PATTERN = re.compile(r' +')
# or
# WHITE_SPACE_PATTERN = re.compile(r'\s+')
# if you want to handle newlines as well

sample_string = "0  45  1  31  2  54  3  54  4  64"
cleaned_string = re.sub(WHITE_SPACE_PATTERN, ' ', sample_string.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)  to match one or more spaces (`' +'`, where `+` implies "one or more") and substitute them with a single space:

```
import re
line = ''
file_object  = open("test.txt", "r+")
for line in file_object:
    line=line
print re.sub(' +', ' ',line.lstrip())
```

Answer (score 1):

For any number of extra spaces I would use:

```
line = ' '.join(line.split(' '))
```

or:

```
line = ' '.join(line.split())
```

for all whitespace chars (' \t\n\r\x0b\x0c')